# Caching directories content in RAM - "ram disk" without "disk"?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ramdisk

I have a large C# solution and 16GB RAM. I want ReSharper to work faster with my code. How can I make some files and directories to be always cached in ram?

- They should be flushed to HDD in a background.
- They should be transparently available for applications with their respective HDD paths.

Comment: There're disk ram cache software available like PrimoCache(http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-cache/download.html) or SuperCache(http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php). Never used any though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make some files and directories to be always cached in ram?

After you have accessed them the disk buffers from the OS should already do that. No need to tweak anything here.

If you want to set this up for faster access on the first run, then you can install a persistent ramdisk. Basically doing this:

Boot:

- Creates ramdisk.
- Copies folders to RAMdisk.

Work:

- You access the files in the fast RAM disk

Shutdown:

- Save ramdisk content back to the folders.
- or: crash: loose all changes.

> They should be transparently available for applications with their
>   respective HDD paths.

Maybe some crazy jugling with junctions or symlinks during the startup and shutdown?

A much simpler solution would be to buy a SSD and put the files on that. Less complex, less risk and quite cheap these days.

Comment: I use encrypted truecrypt image because I don't want my files to be available when I'm not using them. So I can't copy to SSD. "OS should already do that" - I don't know, it looks pretty slow.

Comment: Then first measure why it seems slow. Does the decrypting add lag? If it is not that then you could always move the truecrypt image to a SSD. Or just use wholedisk encryption on the SSD.